# How can I use Pandera to assert whether a column has one of multiple data types?

Tags: python, pandas, pydantic, typing, pandera

My Pandas dataframes need to adhere to the following Pandera schema:

```
import pandera as pa
from pandera.typing import Series

class schema(pa.SchemaModel):
    name: Series[str]
    id: Series[str]
```

However, in some dataframe instances, the "id" column will only contain integers and thus will get the "int" datatype when using `pd.read_csv()`.

For example, I have the following dataframe:

[image: example of a dataframe containing columns "name" and "id" with three rows, where "id" is always an integer]

When I run `schema(df).validate()` I get the error: `pandera.errors.SchemaError: expected series 'id' to have type str, got int64`

However, in other cases the dataframe might look something like this:

[image: example of a dataframe containing columns "name" and "id" with three rows, where "id" is sometimes a string]

I would like to account for both situations by allowing the column to be one of both datatypes.

This is what I tried (but it doesn't seem to be the correct syntax, as the validation method won't run):

```
import pandera as pa
from pandera.typing import Series
from typing import Union

class schema(pa.SchemaModel):
    name: Series[str]
    id: Union[Series[str], Series[int]]
```

Is there any way to do this in Pandera?

Comment: What error do you get specifically? _(Could be helpful to share a sample dataframe you are trying validate.)_

Comment: Interested if you found a solution to this!

Answer (score 0):

It's not implemented yet: https://github.com/unionai-oss/pandera/issues/1152

There is also a linked pull request that seems stale since a couple of months:
https://github.com/unionai-oss/pandera/pull/1227